# python reset enumerate index of a list on condition

Tags: python, list, loops

i want to loop through list1 and append an increasing value to list2 until it reaches a value in list1 where `value != 0` then that increasing value resets back to `0` and starts enumerating from `0` again.

I tried the following:

```
list1 = [0,0,0,25,0,0,0,20,0,0]
list2 = []

for i,v in enumerate(list1):
    if v == 0:
        list2.append(i+1)
    else:
        list2.append(0)
```

But this returns:

```
list2 = [1,2,3,0,5,6,7,0,9,10]
```

Desired output:

```
list2 = [1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `for` and `enumerate(..)` is that `for` **does not care about setting variables like `i`** in the loop: if a new iteration is started, then `i` is fetched from the iterator that feeds to the `for`. So even if you set `i`, it will have no effect the next iteration.

The trick is thus to define `i` out of the loop and update it yourself (increment it, or reset it if `v != 0`):

```
list1 = [0,0,0,25,0,0,0,20,0,0]
list2 = []

i = 0
for v in list1:
    i += 1
    if v != 0:
        i = 0
    list2.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enumerating, you can set an accumulator which can be reset to zero if the value in *`list1`* is not equal to zero:

```
list2 = []

acc = 0
for v in list1:
    if v != 0:
        list2.append(0)
        acc = 0
    else:
        acc += 1
        list2.append(acc)

list2
# [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]
```